# Android crash during fragment replace action

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am writing a simple app to learn Java, specifically how to manage fragment transactions.

The app has one MainActivity and three fragments (FragmentDefault, added to the MainActivity by default; and Fragments one and two, which can be added on a button click in MainActivity).

My app can handle on fragment transaction, but crashes during the second, regardless of the order of the transactions.

The MainActivity.java file is as follows:

```js
package com.example.connor.fragmenttestapp;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentDefault fragDefault = new FragmentDefault();
    Fragment1 frag1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment2 frag2 = new Fragment2();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragDefault)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void openFrag(View view) {
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag1);
        transaction.commit();
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    }

    public void openFrag2(View view) {
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag2);
        transaction.commit();
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
}
```

with .XML file:

```js
package com.example.connor.fragmenttestapp;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentDefault fragDefault = new FragmentDefault();
    Fragment1 frag1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment2 frag2 = new Fragment2();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragDefault)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void openFrag(View view) {
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag1);
        transaction.commit();
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    }

    public void openFrag2(View view) {
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag2);
        transaction.commit();
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
}
```

My three fragment files are essentially identical with java files:

```js
package com.example.connor.fragmenttestapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }
}
```

and .XML files:

```js
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.connor.fragmenttestapp.Fragment1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/frag1_text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />


</FrameLayout>
```

The logcat file for this error shows :

> 02-01 21:01:51.608 15413-15413/com.example.connor.fragmenttestapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: com.example.connor.fragmenttestapp, PID: 15413
>                                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10896)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22546)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702) 
>                                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10896) 
>                                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22546) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
>                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:630)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:603)
>                                                                                               at com.example.connor.fragmenttestapp.MainActivity.openFrag2(MainActivity.java:37)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702) 
>                                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10896) 
>                                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22546) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

What is causing this error and how can I fix the code to avoid it?

Comment: You are somehow calling commit twice.

Comment: Please see this for help on writing a good question / debugging issues like this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You're using the same `FragmentTransaction` everywhere. Don't do that. Just call `beginTransaction()` each time you need one. And move the `addToBackStack()` calls to before the `commit()` calls.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called` what else do you need?

Comment: you can't commit a transaction twice. You need a new transaction each time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to begin a transaction each time instead of creating only one.

You can have a single FragmentManager, but must beginTransition every time.

```js
package com.example.connor.fragmenttestapp;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentDefault fragDefault = new FragmentDefault();
    Fragment1 frag1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment2 frag2 = new Fragment2();
    FragmentManager fm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fm = = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragDefault)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void openFrag(View view) {
    fm.beginTransition().replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag1)
        .addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }

    public void openFrag2(View view) {
    fm.beginTransition().replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag2);
        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this two functions

```
    public void openNoHistoryFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container,
                    fragment);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

        public void openFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
//            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);

            transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

create this each time when your want to make transaction.
transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();